# Consume a "WCF Service" in "Classical ASP" respectively in VB6

Tags: wcf, vb6, asp-classic, com+

Is there a simple way to consume a WCF Service from Classical ASP respectively in VB6 ?
Is it possible to provide a WCF Service as a COM+ Service (component) ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following articles will help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735856.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733928.aspx